# How to add additional row in result set?

Tags: sql-server

I have this query which is returning the attendance time of the employee on each day.

```
SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(COALESCE(AttendanceTimeIn, AttendanceTimeOut) AS DATE)) RN, FirstName+' '+LastName EmployeeName, 
            CAST(COALESCE(AttendanceTimeIn, AttendanceTimeOut) AS DATE) DateOn, 
            CAST(COALESCE(AttendanceTimeIn, AttendanceTimeOut) AS TIME) AttendanceTime,
            CASE WHEN AttendanceTimeIn IS NOT NULL THEN 'Time In' WHEN AttendanceTimeOut IS NOT NULL THEN 'Time Out' END Status

            FROM HRM.tbl_EmployeeAttendance
            INNER JOIN HRM.tbl_EmployeeInfo ON tbl_EmployeeAttendance.EmpCode = tbl_EmployeeInfo.ID
```

I want to return equal number of rows on each day, right now it's returning following rows like this.

```
1   Yousuf Abdullah 2019-03-01  08:31:37.0000000    Time In
2   Yousuf Abdullah 2019-03-02  06:27:37.0000000    Time Out
3   Yousuf Abdullah 2019-03-02  13:12:12.0000000    Time In
4   Yousuf Abdullah 2019-03-03  13:12:12.0000000    Time In
```

I want the result set to be something like this.

```
1   Yousuf Abdullah 2019-03-01  08:31:37.0000000    Time In1
2   Yousuf Abdullah 2019-03-01  NULL                Time Out1
3   Yousuf Abdullah 2019-03-01  NULL                Time In2
4   Yousuf Abdullah 2019-03-01  NULL                Time Out2
1   Yousuf Abdullah 2019-03-02  NULL                Time In1
2   Yousuf Abdullah 2019-03-02  06:27:37.0000000    Time Out1
3   Yousuf Abdullah 2019-03-02  13:12:12.0000000    Time In2
4   Yousuf Abdullah 2019-03-02  NULL                Time Out2
1   Yousuf Abdullah 2019-03-03  13:12:12.0000000    Time In1
2   Yousuf Abdullah 2019-03-03  NULL                Time Out1
3   Yousuf Abdullah 2019-03-03  NULL                Time In2
4   Yousuf Abdullah 2019-03-03  NULL                Time Out2
```

What I actually want is to return 4 rows or more up to 10 Time Ins and Out if possible for each day. If the time in or out exists for that day it'll fill up the slot else it will return NULL or something.

Here is the sample data

```
CREATE TABLE HRM.tbl_EmployeeInfo
(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
FirstName VARCHAR(25),
LastName VARCHAR(25)
);

CREATE TABLE HRM.tbl_EmployeeAttendance
(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
EmpCode INT,
AttendanceTimeIn datetime,
AttendanceTimeOut datetime
);


INSERT [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeAttendance]   VALUES (1, 453, CAST(N'2019-03-01T08:31:37.000' AS DateTime), NULL);
INSERT [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeAttendance]   VALUES (2, 453, CAST(N'2019-03-02T06:27:37.000' AS DateTime), NULL);
INSERT [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeAttendance]   VALUES (3, 453, CAST(N'2019-03-02T13:12:12.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2019-03-02T14:15:16.000' AS DateTime));
INSERT [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeAttendance]   VALUES (4, 453, CAST(N'2019-03-03T13:12:12.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2019-03-03T14:15:16.000' AS DateTime));
```

Comment: I hope some day I will not feel the need to upvote a question for proper sample data and expected result, but it is not this day. Yet.

Comment: why is `2019-03-02  06:27:37` a `Time Out` ?

Comment: Employee have the option to select Check In and Check Out themselves from machine so user might have mistakenly marked checked in instead of check out